# Renewal of Indian passport for NRIs

Tags: indian-citizens, passports, passport-renewals

I am an Indian citizen living in Germany. I am applying for my passport renewal from India and in the online application, there is a question:

Is your present address out of India? *Yes No

When I select Yes, it asks me for a proof Of Present Residential Address.

There is a list of accepted documents present in this link for residential address proof https://portal1.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/popuponline/AttachmentAdvisorSub?subDocID=7001&minorFlag=2 However, none of these documents state my German address.

How do I supply the proof of my present residential address?

Comment: That’s quite a comprehensive list of possible documents. You really don’t have any of them? No certificate from employer, for example? How long have you been living in Germany?

Comment: Yes, I do have a blue card that states my German address and I am living in Germany for 4 years.  I have read in a lot of posts available online that I should say No to "Is your present address out of India?" question as the present address is the address where you apply for the passport.

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned link is for Indian addresses. For foreign addresses, any official address proof will suffice for practice.

I live in Singapore and I provided my mobile phone bill as address proof for renewal. Your blue card stating German address will be more than enough as an address proof. You can opt the passport to be sent to that address.